# Multiple level inheritance in EF 5.0. Crash Edmx on update from database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orm

I got a simple test project to demonstrate a problem in my work project.

My edmx model looks like this: [image]

Everything works fine.
But, when I add a new field in Test table in my DB and do update my edmx model, I got an error:

> Problem in mapping fragments starting at lines 108, 114:No mapping
>   specified for  properties BaseHistoryEntity.CREATED_DATE in Set
>   BaseEntitySet. An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
>   Entity is type [Model.TABLE1]

So, when I open edmx file as xml, I found, that `CREATED_DATE` field of `Table1` in c-s mapping content section is disappeared:

```
<MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="TABLE1">
  <ScalarProperty Name="Id" ColumnName="ID" />
  <ScalarProperty Name="TABLE2_ID" ColumnName="TABLE2_ID" />
  <ScalarProperty Name="FIELD1" ColumnName="FIELD1" />
 </MappingFragment>
```

When I add manually

```
<ScalarProperty Name="CREATED_DATE" ColumnName="CREATED_DATE" />
```

My pgoject builds without errors and all is fine. When I update my edmx model once more. `CREATED_DATE` field will disappeare again.

Is it a bug of EntityFramework? Very uncomfortable to add fields manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can not edit the xml file nor the designer class since they are auto-generated in if you do edit them you wont have build errors but u will differently have an unexpected behavior